# Commit to gerrit approach

Tags: git, gerrit

What is the best approach of merging the commits into one into gerrit?
The problem is as follows:

For small stories I need to have max two commits. So far my review failed 2 times, and now, the third time I need to commit and I need to have max 2 patchsets not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is the following:
If it is the first time, commit + review. Simple as that. 
Second, third,etc I commit, than create a review branch and do a Squash.

You should see something like that:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~4

pick 01d1125 Do smth
s 6340aah Do smth 2
s ebfd369 Do smth 3
s 30e0ccb Fixed the review.

# Rebase 60709da..30e0ccb onto 60709da
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```